# MIcrosoft.Identity.Web: onTokenValidated Event in .net core web api

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Trying to configure authentication in .net core web api using Microsoft.Identity.Web. I want to put some custom logic within onTokenValidated Event but it doesnt get triggered.Here is the Configuration code:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
        {
            configuration.Bind("Authentication:AzureADB2C", options);
            options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                {
                    //some logic
                    return;
                },
                OnAuthenticationFailed =  context => 
                {
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
```

Here is my appsettings.json:

```json
"Authentication": {
    "AzureADB2C": {
      "TenantId": "",
      "Instance": "https://<>.b2clogin.com", // default : https://<tenantName>.b2clogin.com
      "ClientId": "", //client id of the api app regeistered on azure
      "Domain": ".onmicrosoft.com", //default : <tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com
      "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1A_signup_signin", // signup policy (in our case custom policy)
      "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1A_signup_signin" // Callback path
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to configure it. I am new to Azure ADB2C

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new event instance, try just adding another delegate to the appropriate property, for example:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
        {
            configuration.Bind("Authentication:AzureADB2C", options);
            options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
            options.Events.OnTokenValidated += async context =>
            {
                //some logic
                return;
            };
            options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed +=  context => 
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });
```

Your appsettings config section looks okay to me, so if the above doesn't work you may need to check that there's not a problem happening earlier in the process, for example before an auth code/tokens are returned to your app, or when your app exchanges an auth code for tokens.